# Необычный цикл foreach

Tags: java, spring, foreach, for

Увидел в проекте(Spring) вот такой код:

```
manRepository.findAll().forEach(mans::add);
```

Что за такой интересный forEach?
я знаком только с таким:

```
for(int i: list(массив или коллекция)){
       //тело цикла
}
```

Comment: Это `Stream API`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это `forEach` для коллекций, который принимает лямбду, а саму лямбду можно заменить ссылкой на метод

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList();
ints.add(1);
ints.add(2);
List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList();
ints.forEach(copy::add);
ints.forEach(oneIntFromInts -> copy.add(oneIntFromInts)); //эквивалент строке выше
copy.forEach(oneIntFromCopy -> System.out.println(oneIntFromCopy));
```